# XML schema validation against sister elements

Tags: xml, xsd-validation, xml-validation

Here is my XML file. This file has to be validated against the following conditions

1. The child -> child1 -> parentData -> name element should be present in parent -> parent* -> name
2. The total length (4 + 3 = 7 in this case) of the children of a particular parent (Parent 2) should be equal to the length element of that element
3. If the part 4-6 of Parent2 is used by child1, no other child should use the same part of Parent2
   and many more...

Please help me with how should I validate this XML file. I tried generating a XSD file from Visual Studio and was able to implement a unique constraint for the parent and child names.

```
<sample>
    <parent>
      <parent1>
        <name>Parent 1</name>
        <length>10</length>
      </parent1>
      <parent2>
        <name>Parent 2</name>
        <length>7</length>
      </parent2>
      <parent3>
        <name>Parent 3</name>
        <length>20</length>
      </parent3>
    </parent>
    <child>
      <child1>
        <length>3</length>
        <parentData>
          <name>Parent 2</name>
          <start>4</start>
          <stop>6</stop>
        </parentData>
      </child1>
      <child2>
        <length>4</length>
        <parentData>
          <name>Parent 2</name>
          <start>0</start>
          <stop>3</stop>
        </parentData>
      </child2>
    </child>
  </sample>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the validity of an element in XSD only depends on the recursive content of that element, never on its siblings, parents, or ancestors. This tells you that a rule defining constraints between `<parent>` and `<child>` elements (I'll use angle brackets for element names to avoid confusion with axis names) has to go on the `<sample>` element: that's the element that's invalid if the constraint is invalid.

Also note that use of element names like `child1` and `child2` isn't making your life easier. If two elements represent the same real-world entity and have the same internal structure and rules, then give them the same name.

> ```
> The child -> child1 -> parentData -> name element should be present in parent -> parent* -> name
> ```

That's a key/keyref defined on `<sample>`. The key has selector = `parent//name`, field = `.`; the keyref has selector = `child//parentData/name`, field = `.`.

```
>     The total length (4 + 3 = 7 in this case) of the children of a particular parent (Parent 2) should be equal to the length element of
> that element
```

That needs assertions, and therefore XSD 1.1. Again it's an assertion defined on `<sample>`, and it's going to be something like `every $p in parent/* satisfies $p/length = sum(child/*[parentData/name = $p/name]/length)`.

> If the part 4-6 of Parent2 is used by child1, no other child should
>   use the same part of Parent2 and many more...

That one's much harder and I'm not going to attempt it. Again it's an assertion on `<sample>`. As a hint, if you assume that `start<end` has already been validated, then I think you can express the constraint that two children $c1 and $c2 don't overlap as `($c1/end < $c2/start or $c2/end < @c1/start)`. So the constraint will take the form `every $c1 in XXX, $c2 in XXX satisfies ($c1 is $c2 or $c1/end < $c2/start or $c2/end < @c1/start)`